# What does this SUMIF formula do?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a SUMIF formula that I can't figure out:

```
AB1/SUMIF(E:E,E1,AB:AB)
```

Column E contains text values: Other, Specific

Column AB contains dollar values.

I don't understand how the criteria evaluates to the range. Is it just looking for that value within that range? If so, wouldn't it always evaluate to yes? By always evaluate to yes I mean that for any value that is plugged in, e.g., E3, E5, E10, the criteria is true.

Comment: My understanding is that E:E and AB:AB refer to the entire column as a range.

Comment: I think the formula is broken. How can you evaluate all of column E against an expression in E1 if that expression evaluates against itself? ">100>100" is a broken logical statement. Are you getting errors on the spreadsheet? EDIT: Nevermind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would translate that into English as: `AB1` divided by the sum of things in column `AB` on rows where the value in column `E` for that row is equal to the value in `E1`.

Comment: So for row two then it would translate as: "...value in Column E for that row is equal to the value in E2"? Because as the rows increase, the row in the criteria also increases.

Comment: Yes, as the other `E:E` and `AB:AB` are columns, only the criteria (`E1`) and the `AB1` would change as the formula is copied down.

Comment: So then it's just checking if the value in column E for that row, e.g., E1, is equal to the value in E1? So always true?

Comment: It is checking to find all rows where the current value in `E` appears and then returning the sum of the values for the `AB` column where those match. So if there were six other matches for the value in `E#` it would return the sum of six values from `AB` for those rows.

Comment: Ah. Ok, I see what you're saying now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Googled: SUMIF 
First result: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx

> **Syntax**
>
> **SUMIF**(range,criteria,sum_range)
>
> **Range**     is the range of cells that you want evaluated by criteria.
>
> **Criteria**     is the criteria in the form of a number, expression, or
>   text that defines which cells will be added. For example, criteria can
>   be expressed as 32, "32", ">32", or "apples".
>
> **Sum_range**     are the actual cells to add if their corresponding cells
>   in range match criteria. If sum_range is omitted, the cells in range
>   are both evaluated by criteria and added if they match criteria.

In your case, all values in column E are evaluated against a logical expression in E1, then sums all of AB if that logical expression against E1 is true.

EDIT: I forgot about AB1 dividing the SUMIF, but you guys get the idea.

Comment: I Googled the answer, but the examples for criteria don't include this particular case. Thanks for letting me know Google exists, however.

Comment: "Against a logical expression in E1" There's just a text value in E1.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is the text? EDIT: nevermind, I get it.

Comment: Every cell in E that contains a value (it stops at row 300 something) includes either "Other" or "Specific" as a text value.

Answer (score 0):

[A picture is worth several hundred words.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_picture_is_worth_a_thousand_words) 
Imagine that you’re running a hotel, and you ask your guests what state they’re from.

[image: Snapshot of hotel registry implemented in Excel]

Column `AC` is the formula from your question. 
It is showing that 20% of the Alaskans in the hotel are in Room 101, 100% of the Californians are in Room 102, 50% of the Texans are in Room 103, etc.

Perhaps a more practical application
would have salesmen in Column `A` and sales in Column `AB`,
so you can see that George Miller has made 42% of the sales in Maine.